# Breakpoint called on commented line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This has me completely lost. 
It almost seems like a bug in VS but I'm sure it's just something I'm doing wrong.

While debugging my code I noticed one function in particular was triggering a breakpoint - without ever being called. I verified from the hierarchy and by searching for all references that nothing was calling it.

Then I commented out the code; and it was still hitting the breakpoint (yes, on the commented line).

Then I moved the commented code and found that the function was no longer being called but another commented string around the same lines was.

It turns out that any line on this .cpp between lines 31 and 43 - even if between functions or commented out - will trigger a breakpoint, even if nothing is there.

for instance:

```
void Namespace::Foo()
{
    ... code ...
}

<<<<< THIS TRIGGERS A BREAKPOINT!>>>>>

void Namespace::Bar()
{
    ... code ...
}
```

I've noticed elsewhere if I try to set a breakpoint outside of a function the breakpoint will automatically move to the next function beneath. But these points will actually stay where I place them.

Is this a known bug?
Is it something I'm doing wrong?
Could it involve inline functions or macros declared on the header?
Is there a workaround or fix?

Edit: Call Stack:

```
>   DirectX.dll!ErrHandling::ErrHandling() Line 31  C++
    DirectX.dll!Write(wchar_t * level, const char * func, long nLine, wchar_t * line) Line 140  C++
    DirectX.dll!cDirectX::Init(int parms, int screenWidth, int screenHeight, HWND__ * hwnd) Line 32 C++
    ProjectDawn.exe!System::Initialize() Line 100   C++
    ProjectDawn.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) Line 51   C++
    [External Code] 
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]
```

It's the top line(31). This is between two different functions:

```
void ErrHandling::vDX_WRITE(const TCHAR* text)
{
    _TCHAR str[MAX_PATH] = _T("");

    // Start with date/time
    LPTSTR string = mFormatTimeNow();
    _tcscat_s(str, 100, string);

    _tcscat_s(str, _MAX_PATH, text); // Write the specific string

    mWriteToFile(str); // Dispatch to file
}
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<LINE 31>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
const TCHAR* ErrHandling::stringFromError(TCHAR* szErr, long nSize, long nErr)
{
    _ASSERTE(szErr);
    *szErr = 0;
    DWORD cb = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, nErr, 0, szErr, nSize, 0);
    TCHAR szUnk[] = _T("<unknown>");
    if (!cb && nSize >= lengthof(szUnk)) lstrcpy(szErr, szUnk);
    return szErr;
}
```

Comment: It might be a lot of different things, but since you didn't paste your actual code it's hard to say.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm not sure what to paste of the code, it happens no matter what code I put there. It's like the file itself is corrupt

Comment: What does the callstack look like?  Are you trying to debug an optimized build?  Have you tried deleting all build artifacts and rebuilding?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Optimization disabled. Cleaned. Rebuilt. Still happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen similar issue that turned out to be caused by different line endings used in a single source file - some line endings were unix style (LF) and some were windows (CRLF). I am not sure if it is possible to see line endings in visual studio editor but there is File -> Advanced Save option to forecefully convert them on save.

Comment: Bingo! thanks much. The File > Advanced Save Options menu has to be enabled from customization. The improper formatting must have been somehow copied over from a different page or maybe from my comment blocks.